# Tkinter - How to create a custom Tkinter Frame object? I tried but it doesn't work

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, customization

I tried to create some custom tkinter objects to build my GUIs easier but unfortunately I couldn't. For example, what about if I want an object that identify a frame placed inside another one? To do that I wrote it:

Main code (file name: `test.py`):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttk_plus as ttkp # my custom library

parent=tk.Tk()
parent.geometry("686x424+370+100")
parent.title("Test")
parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
parent.minsize(686, 424)

MyFrame=ttkp.Frame(parent) # my custom object
MyFrame.pack(padx=(5,5), pady=(5,5))

parent.mainloop()
```

Library (file name: `ttk_plus.py`):

```
class Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        
        self.container=container
        
        # definisco il frame principale:
        self.Frame1=tk.Frame(self.container, background="white")
        
        # definisco il frame secondario:
        self.Frame2=tk.Frame(self.Frame1, background="white", highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=1)
        self.Frame2.pack(padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 5), fill=tk.BOTH)
```

If I run `test.py`, the software start without any kind of issues, but I can't see my object inside the main window. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a custom frame, every widget created in this frame needs to be a descendant of the frame, not the container. Otherwise, `Frame` will affect its parent in unexpected ways.

```
self.Frame1=tk.Frame(self, background="white")
```

You also need to make sure you call some geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, `grid`) on this inner frame. Otherwise, this frame and any widgets in it won't be visible.

Since it's the only direct child in the container, `pack` is the simplest:

```
self.Frame1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Finally, since at the moment you're only creating frames, you'll likely want to either give the frame a size, or use geometry manager attributes that cause it to fill the window.

```
MyFrame.pack(padx=(5,5), pady=(5,5), fill="both", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom frame, `Frame1` is the parent of `Frame2`. You have packed `Frame2` but not its parent, hence it's simply not in your window.

### Fix

Try to pack your `Frame1`:

```
self.Frame1=tk.Frame(self.container, background="white")
self.Frame1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

And the result would be:
[image]

Just to check its working properly, try adding a sample button to the `Frame2`
[image]